# SQL server - Client Connection works in one network not on another

Tags: sql-server, networking

We cannot access from a client computer (Client) to a SQL Server computer (Server) on network A but successfully on another B. The Server computer has SQL Server 2019 installed, the Client computer has SQL Native Client 11.0 installed. We can connect from this client to the server in on network A either using sqlcmd, udl interface, or Telnet. But on a different network B, we cannot connect from the same Client to the same Server! What network configuration can avoid a SQL Server connection?

Server Parameters:

```
1. We defined firewall rules to allow inbound connection on ports 1433 for TCP and 1434 for UDP. We verified that that is the case on the Server by using "netstat -aon". We disabled the Norton Smart Firewall.

2. We have set this rule to apply to all profiles: Domain, Public, Private.

3. We ensured that all protocols for SQLEXPRESS are allowed and enabld in the SQL Server Configuration Manager, specifically TCP/IP. 

4. We have enabled SQL Server Browser.

5. We have restarted all services multiple times after our configuration changes. We have even restarted the machine.

6. We made sure that the Server is accessible remotely and using SQL Server Authentication. 

7. We reset both the modem and the router for both Networks before testing. 

8. We confirmed both the Computer and the SQL Instance names in the SMSS logins and logs.

Tests we did on Network A:

1. We can ping the Client from the Server, the Server from the Client both with IP addresses and computer names (On Server: "ping -a ClientIP/ComputerName", On Client: "ping -a ServerIP/ComputerName". Both results with "Reply...").

2. We can access the database in the Server using SSMS both with Windows Authentication and SQL Server Authentication.  

3. We cannot access to Server from the Client by Windows Authentication either by using "sqlcmd -S Server\sqlexpress -E".

4. We cannot access to Server from the Client by SQL Server Authentication by using "sqlcmd -U User -P Password -S Server\SQLExpress".

On the other hand, when these computers are in Network B, without changing anything we can connect to Server from the Client.
```

Here are the error messages we get:

sqlcmd -U User -P Password -S Server\SQLExpress

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default named instances use dynamic ports, which you're not allowing through the firewall.

The best solution is probably to simply configure the SQL Server instance to listen on the fixed port 1433, then you don't need to use an Instance Name or explicit port to connect.

To do this us [SQL Server Configuration Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/tcp-ip-properties-ip-addresses-tab?view=sql-server-ver15) to configure the instance to listen on port 1433 on all IPs.  It should look like this:

[image]

With Dynamic Ports blank, and 1433 in the TCP IP port.

Then restart the SQL Server instance and in the SQL Server Logs you should see a message like

```
Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv4> 1433].
```

Then try to connect like

```
sqlcmd -U User -P Password -S Server
```

And you can test with Powershell

```
  PS C:\> test-netconnection Server -port 1433
```

If you do this you won't need the SQL Browser Service or the firewall rule for port 1434.

Comment: I had already had done that. The test "test-netconnection Server -port 1433" returns False, but "test-netconnection ServerIP -port 1433" true.

Comment: (where ServerIP is IP address of the computer). So I can ping the server on the 1433 port fine, but I cannot access it. The SQL Server Logs show "Server is listening on ['any' <ipv4. 1433]". In any case, whatever the configuration of the SQL Server is, I can access it from the same Client computer to this same computer on a different network (Wireless)! So what nerwork configuration of this wireless network is forbidding this connection?

Comment: And this problem is the same for several Server and Client computers. I cannot connect to the Servers from Client computers. Certainly, this was not the case. Something changed in our network configuration.

Comment: When I used a wired network instead of wireless I was able to connect on this network as well. It seems there is something in wireless networks that somehow can't connect the client to the server.